# How to use ints in a protobuf struct?

Tags: int, protocol-buffers

I have noticed that when converting a Python dictionary to a google.protobuf.Struct the integers are turned into floats, i.e. this:

```python
my_dict = {'id': 42}
```

becomes this:

```proto
fields {
    key: "id"
    value {
        number_value: 42.0
    }
}
```

This is very unfortunate, but looking at the [proto definition of struct](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/struct.proto) it seems that this is by design as there is indeed only a double number value.

Does anyone know the reason for this, and is there way around this without manually keeping track of which numbers are ints and which are floats?

Comment: I agree it is odd - I could *speculate* that the thought process was something like "well, how far do we take it? do we have different fields for signed vs unsigned integers? 32-bit vs 64-bit? fixed size, varint, and zig-zag + varint? and 32-bit vs 64-bit floating point? (so: 14 fields for the numbers, if you're counting) Or... since a `double` can cover most of the useful values, shall we just go with one `double` field? if they want something more specific, folks can define a `message`"

Comment: But you can't use a custom message in place of a predefined struct field, or can you? A lot of Googles own APis use struct as the type for JSON, but that isn't really usable if the struct has even fewer types than JSON itself.

Comment: no, not in place of `Value` / `Struct`, no

Answer (score 1):

As `com.google.protobuf.Struct` is create to store JSON data, it follows JSON specification which does not differentiate between Integer and Float:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#page-6

There are implementation of JSON that provide Integer data type such as [JSONObject](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html).  However, such implementation often rely on casting numeric to Integer.  See [JsonNumber.isIntegral](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonNumber.html#isIntegral--).

Comment: The problem is that `com.google.protobuf.struct.Value` actively *casts integers* to floats. `print(google.protobuf.struct_pb2.Value(number_value=5))` yields `5.0` and not `5`.

Comment: The JSON in practice differentiates between integers and floats. `1` being an integer, and `1.0` being a float.  Lots of people get this wrong and think that JSON is just JavaScript, but really JSON numbers are unbounded decimals, and it's trivial to work out if a decimal is an integer or not.

Comment: "This specification allows implementations to set limits on the range and precision of numbers accepted."

Python doesn't have limits on how large integer numbers can be and allows arbitrarily large values in its json parser.

Comment: Just as you say, JSON is not just for one language.  It might be trivial in Python to work out if a number is integer or not but how do you know if it's a Java Int, Long or something that goes beyond 64bit that requires BigDecimal?  It really comes down to documenting your JSON in such a way that receiver knows what type of number they are getting.  There is simple no easy way to work it out by just looking at a JSON.